# Fill NaN values in a pandas DataFrame depending on values of cells to its left

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to fill NaN's in a very large pandas dataframe with zeros, but only if there are non-NaN values in the same row but in a cell to its left. So for example, from this input DataFrame,

`input = pd.DataFrame([[1, np.NaN, 1.5, np.NaN], [np.NaN, 2, np.NaN, np.NaN]], index=['A', 'B'], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])`

which looks like:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
A   1.0     NaN     1.5     NaN
B   NaN     2.0     NaN     NaN
```

The expected output would be:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
A   1.0     0       1.5     0
B   NaN     2.0     0       0
```

See how [B, col1] remains a Nan because there's no not-NaN value to its left, but all four [A,col2], [A, col4], [B,col3] and [B, col4] have been filled with zeros (because there are leftier non-NaN values).

Does anyone have any idea on how to go on about this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use forward filling missing values and test not missing and chain by test missing values and by this mask assign `0`:

```
df[df.ffill(axis=1).notna() & df.isna()] = 0
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
A   1.0   0.0   1.5   0.0
B   NaN   2.0   0.0   0.0
```

Or you can use cumulative sum with test not equal `0` values:

```
df[df.fillna(0).cumsum(axis=1).ne(0) & df.isna()] = 0
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
A   1.0   0.0   1.5   0.0
B   NaN   2.0   0.0   0.0
```